# Please help me find the two leaks in this iOS code

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, ios5, ios-simulator

In my `viewController.m` I have this code:

```
self.movie = [[myMovie alloc]init];
self.movie.name = @"Iron man 2"; \\this line leaks
```

...

```
nameLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 20, 200, 20)]; \\this line leaks
nameLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In `viewController.h` I have this code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
    myMovie * movie;

    UILabel * nameLbl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) myMovie * movie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel * nameLbl;
```

And myMovie.h:

```
{
    NSString* name;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
```

myMovie.m:

```
#import "myMovie.h"

@implementation myMovie
@synthesize name, gross, desc;



-(void) dealloc
{
    self.name = nil;
    self.gross = nil;
    self.desc = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Of course this is only the necessary code. I can't figure out why it is leaking. I don't know if this is the cause but my application crashes.

Comment: What's telling you that that line leaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line that's leaking is the one above:  `self.movie = [[myMovie alloc]init];`

Change it to `self.movie = [[[myMovie alloc]init] autorelease];` or add `[self.movie release];` as the line immediately afterwards.

Comment: I did Product->Analyse , you suggestion fix the first leak, thanks! any ideas about the second leak?

Comment: Do the same with nameLbl. The values set to these variables are retained by the synthesized setter methods since they are declared with the "retain" attribute. The values you pass in should be autoreleased.

Comment: I did like this: nameable = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 20, 200, 20)] autorelease]; and its still leaks

Comment: @nir -- Try `self.nameLbl = [[[... autorelease];`.